# Swift/xCode error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to iOS programming and am currently doing an Intro to xCode and Swift tutorial on Udacity (PitchPerfect). We’re building a simple two-view app which will record a voice (first ViewController), then play it back on the 2nd VC.

As part of the tutorial, we’re supposed to add an extension (AVAudioPlayerDelegate) to our project which allows the 2nd VC to play back audio in different effects (e.g., fast, slow, echo, reverb, etc).  Adding this extension file, called playsoundsviewcontroller-audio.swift,  to my xCode project resulted in the following runtime crash:

Thread1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode

Code snippets and screen shot attached. Note, I have not modified this extension except for the 4 Print commands—I simply imported it into my project according to the instructions from the course instructor. The console shows “index out of range”, and the problem Is obviously with “nodes[x+1].”  I’ve also printed out some variables to aid in solving this, including x, nodes.count, and the nodes array.

Anyone have any idea why this doesn’t work?  Probably easy to spot for an experienced programmer…

```
func connectAudioNodes(_ nodes: AVAudioNode...) {
    for x in 0...nodes.count-1 {
        audioEngine.connect(nodes[x], to: nodes[x+1], format: audioFile.processingFormat)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately , StackOverflow will not let me upload a screen shot to this question, I just discovered.

Comment: can you post more of this classes code. Its hard to tell with just that small snippet of code. however your index out of range is because say you have 10 elements in your array that would be 0-9. count is 10 so you would iterate from 0-9 however when you get to 9 and you try to index 9+1 you are out of bounds of the array.

Comment: Thank you Maddy. This fixed the problem.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop

```
for x in 0...nodes.count-1 {
```

which is by the way the same as the recommended operator

```
for x in 0..<nodes.count {
```

in the last iteration `x` is the last index and `x+1` is **out of bounds** which causes the exception.

---

A solution is to iterate until the second last index

```
for x in 0..<nodes.count-1 {
```

Comment: Thank you Vadian, for the quick reply. Fixed the problem. Much appreciated.